# ToolTip Shiny renderDataTable for only one header name

Tags: r, shiny, tooltip

I have a table in Shiny and want to add **only one tooltip** for the column "Species", i.e. the other columns should not have a tooltip.

I managed to add a tooltip for all of them, but don't know how I can set the content for specific columns.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable(iris,  options = list(
      pageLength = 5,
      initComplete = I("function(settings, json) {
                                      $('th').each( function(){this.setAttribute( 'title', 'TEST' );});  
                                      $('th').tooltip(); 

                                     }")))
                          }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code to get the tooltip for only the 4th column name ie "Species".

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable(iris,  options = list(
      pageLength = 5,
      initComplete = I("function(settings, json) {
                       $('th:eq(4)').each( function(){this.setAttribute( 'title', 'TEST' );});  
                       $('th').tooltip(); 

  }")))

    }
      )
```

Hope this helps!